# Let $\mathbb{R}=A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are mutually separated. Show that $A$ and $B$ are both open.

Tags: real-analysis

The following is an exercise in my textbook.

> Fill in the missing details in the following proof that the Least Upper Bound property implies that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.
>
> (a) Let $\mathbb{R}=A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are mutually separated. Then, $A$ and $B$ are both open.

In my class notes, I have the following written down.

> $\mathbb{R} = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are mutually separated. Mutually separated implies that $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

I wanted to know if someone can give a more detailed explanation as to how mutually separated implies that $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$?

Also in my notes.

> $\mathbb{R} = A \cup B$
>
> $A = \overline{B^c} \rightarrow$ $A$ is open. Similarly, $B$ is open.

So, I understand that $\overline{B^c} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$. But, why does that automatically mean that we can set $A = \overline{B^c}$?

Comment: What does mutually separated mean in this context?

Comment: neither set contains a boundary point of the other.

Comment: So $A \cap (\overline{B} \setminus int(B)) = B \cap (\overline{A} \setminus int(A)) = \emptyset$?

Comment: Is there a missing condition here? Because if $A = B = \mathbb{R}$ then we have that $bd(A) = bd(B) = \emptyset$, so neither $A$ nor $B$ contain a boundary point of the other, but clearly $A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Paul Frost: yes, that's an equivalent way of saying that neither set contains a boundary point of the other

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If mutually disjont requires $A,B \ne \emptyset$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $\mathbb{R} = A \cup B$ is impossible for open $A,B$.